# Chain rule differentiation - what happens with summation?

Tags: summation, partial-derivative, chain-rule, neural-networks

I am currently going through some derivation I made for computing an error term used in neural network, and bit confused on what happened to this summation, at the derivation?

\begin{equation} \label{eq:error_term_node_layer_output}
    \begin{split}
        c &= \frac{1}{2}||{y - a_{i}^{(l)}}||^2 \\
        \delta_{i}^{(l)} &= \frac{\partial c}{\partial z_i^{(l)}}  \\
        & = \frac{\partial c}{\partial z_{i}^{(l+1)}}  \frac{\partial z_{i}^{(l+1)}}{\partial z_i^{(l)}} \\
        z_i^{(l+1)} & =  \sum_{j=1}^{\text{nodes in layer} ~\text{l}} w_{ij}^{(l)} a_{i}^{(l)} + b_i^{(l)}\\
        \frac{\partial c}{\partial z_{i}^{(l+1)}} &= \delta_{j}^{(l+1)}\\
        %&= \sum_{j=1}^{s_{l+1}} w_{ji}^{(l)}  x_{j}^{l} + b^{(l)}\\
        \frac{\partial z_i^{(l+1)}}{\partial a_i^{(l)}} &= \frac{ \partial  }{ \partial z^{(l)}_i } \sum_j W_{ij}^{(l)} f(z_i^{(l)}) + b_i^{(\ell)} \\
        &= W_{ij}^{(l)} f'(z_i^{(l)})\\
        \delta_i^{(l)} &= \delta_{j}^{(l+1)}W_{ij}^{(l)} f'(z_i^{(l)})
        %\delta_i^{(l)} &= \sum_{j=1}^{s_{(l+1)}}\delta_j^{(l+1)}w_{ji}^{(l)} %\delta_i^{(l)} &= f'(z_i^{(l)})\sum_{j=1}^{s_{(l+1)}}\delta_j^{(l+1)}w_{ji}^{(l)} 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

The math is inspired from this http://bigtheta.io/2016/02/27/the-math-behind-backpropagation.html

Comment: You have severe index problems throughout your calculation. $c$ depends on $l$, but you use it as if it didn't. You leave the $b_i^{(l)}$ term inside the sum, despite it not depending on the index of summation $j$ at all. The summation you are asking about does not go away, as $\sum_j W_{ij}^{(l)}$ is the constant multiplier of $f(z_i^{(l)})$, not just $W_{ij}^{(l)}$, as should be clear, since you have $j$ suddenly appearing as an actual variable, where it was only a dummy variable before. I suspect that the various uses of $i$ inside the summations (except on $W$) should have all been $j$.